# How do I parse a nested JSON.I am getting nil value as an output

Tags: ios, json, swift

These are the structs I have created

```
struct main : Decodable{      // these are the values I want to retrieve 
        let catname : String?
        let catid : String?
        let sub_title : String?
        let image : String?
        let contest : [contest]

    enum CodingKeys : String , CodingKey {
        case catname = "catname"
        case catid = "catid"
        case sub_title = "sub_title"
        case image = "image"
        case contest = "contest"
    }

}
struct  contest : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let entryfee : Int
    let contest_type : String
    let winning_percentage : Int
    let win_amount : Int
    let matchkey : String
    let c_type : String
    let status : Int
    let joinedusers : Int
    let maximum_user : Int
    let getjoinedpercentage : String
    let multi_entry : Int
    let confirmed_challenge : Int
    let is_running : Int
    let is_bonus : Int
    let bonus_percentage : Int
    let isselected : Bool
    let isselectedid : String
    let refercode : String
    var price_card : [price_card]
    let totalwinners : Int
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey{
        case id , name , entryfee , contest_type , winning_percentage ,win_amount,matchkey,c_type,status,joinedusers,maximum_user,getjoinedpercentage,multi_entry,confirmed_challenge,is_running,is_bonus,bonus_percentage,isselected,isselectedid,refercode,price_card,totalwinners


    }




}
struct price_card : Decodable {
    let price : String
    let winners : Int
    let start_position :String
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey{
        case price , winners , start_position
    }
```

This is the main code for parsing of the data.The error I am getting while running is Error keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "catid", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"catid\", intValue: nil) (\"catid\").", underlyingError: nil))

```
func experiment1(){
           let Url = URL(string: url)
                var request = URLRequest(url: Url!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("bearer 03a4013d77568a67c159a41f680d14f4",forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: Url!){ data,response,error
                   in
                    guard error == nil else{
                                       print("some error is found",error)
                                       return
                                   }
                                guard let data = data else {
                                 return
                                   }
                    print(data)
                    do{

                       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                        let Main = try decoder.decode(main.self,from: data)


                        print(Main.catid)
                    }
                    catch
                        let jsonErr {
                            print("Error" , jsonErr)
                        }
                    }.resume()
        }
```

---

This is my JSON

```
[{
        "catname": "HOT CONTESTS",
        "catid": 4,
        "sub_title": "Call the shot quickly",
        "image": "https://mybat11.com/admin/public/images_contest_category/contest_1572688096.jpg",
        "contest": [
            {
                "id": 73,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bplt20_2020_g27",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 1,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "1%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 77,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bblt20_2019_g17",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 81,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "c.match.adh_vs_cm.c028d",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 85,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "c.match.ns_vs_wb.63191",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 89,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "sst20_2019_g17",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 93,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "sst20_2019_g18",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 97,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bblt20_2019_g18",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 101,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "c.match.ch_vs_os.c6d23",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 105,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bblt20_2019_g19",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 109,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "sst20_2019_g19",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 113,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bplt20_2020_g29",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 117,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bblt20_2019_g20",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 121,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "bplt20_2020_g30",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 125,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "ausnz_2019_test_03",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 129,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "c.match.wb_vs_ns.7fdc4",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 133,
                "name": "Win Rs.1000",
                "entryfee": 12,
                "contest_type": "Amount",
                "winning_percentage": 0,
                "win_amount": 1000,
                "matchkey": "sst20_2019_g20",
                "c_type": "classic",
                "status": 1,
                "joinedusers": 0,
                "maximum_user": 100,
                "getjoinedpercentage": "0%",
                "multi_entry": 1,
                "confirmed_challenge": 0,
                "is_running": 0,
                "is_bonus": 0,
                "bonus_percentage": 0,
                "multientry_limit": null,
                "isselected": false,
                "isselectedid": "",
                "refercode": "",
                "price_card": [
                    {
                        "price": "Rs.1000",
                        "winners": 1,
                        "start_position": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "totalwinners": 1
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
```

Comment: Unrelated: Use camel-case instead of snake-case for naming your variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. `let catid : String?` should be `let catid : Int?`
2. `let Main = try decoder.decode(main.self,from: data)` should be `let Main = try decoder.decode([main].self,from: data)`

I've fixed it and everything works correctly. I'd like to recommend remove this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let Main = try decoder.decode(main.self,from: data)
print(Main.catid)
```

and add just it:

```
let Main = try? JSONDecoder().decode([main].self, from: data)
print(Main?.first?.catid)
```

From my side, in addition, I recommend reading [the Apple documentation](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) about naming classes and variables.

Comment: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."Now it is showing this error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `catid` has an `Int` value instead of `String`, so

```
let catid : String?
```

must be replaced with

```
let catid : Int?
```

**Note:**

1. Use *camel-case* for naming your variables instead of *snake-case*, i.e. `sub_title` must be named `subTitle` instead.
2. Also, there is no need to explicitly define `enum CodingKeys` if the property names are same as the keys of JSON.

So, your models must be

```
struct Main : Decodable {     
    let catname : String?
    let catid : Int?
    let subTitle : String?
    let image : String?
    let contest : [Contest]
}

struct Contest : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let entryfee : Int
    let contestType : String
    let winningPercentage : Int
    let winAmount : Int
    let matchkey : String
    let cType : String
    let status : Int
    let joinedusers : Int
    let maximumUser : Int
    let getjoinedpercentage : String
    let multiEntry : Int
    let confirmedChallenge : Int
    let isRunning : Int
    let isBonus : Int
    let bonusPercentage : Int
    let isselected : Bool
    let isselectedid : String
    let refercode : String
    var priceCard : [PriceCard]
    let totalwinners : Int
}

struct PriceCard : Decodable {
    let price : String
    let winners : Int
    let startPosition :String
}
```

You can now parse the data the same way you did earlier.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can decode your json ...

```
Alamofire.request(suggurl, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON { response in
                            if response.result.isSuccess{
                                let json = response.result.value! as? [Array<Any>] ?? []
                                let first = json[0] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]

                                let catname = first["catname"] as? Any

                                let catid = first["catid"] as? Any

                                let subtitle = first["sub_title"] as? Any

                                let image = first["image"] as? Any
                                let contest = first["contest"] as? [Any] ?? []

                                for i in 0..<contest.count{
                                    let singlerecord = contest[i] as? [String:Any]
                                    let id = singlerecord?["id"] as? Any ?? ""
                                    let status = singlerecord?["status"] as? Any ?? ""
                                    // and all other elements of singlerecord do same
                                    let price_card = singlerecord?["price_card"] as? [Any] ?? []
                                    let pricecard1 = price_card[0] as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
                                    let price = pricecard1["price"] as? Any ?? ""
                                    //and all elements of price_card do same




                                }

                            }else{
                            }
                        }
```

I hope it will work for you ...:)

Comment: Thanks for that! But I want it to parse json using JSON.I already know how to parse through Alamofire.